# phpinfo()でのバージョン確認について

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

MacのHomebrewにてPHP5.5.29からPHP5.5.30へアップデートしました。
ターミナルにて『php -v』にて5.5.30へのアップデートを確認できたのですが、phpinfo()を実行してみたところ、アップデート前の5.5.29のままでした。phpinfo()にアップデートを反映させるにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Apacheのhttpd.confにて、php5_moduleが5.5.29のものと5.5.30のもの、両方記載されていました。古い5.5.29の方を削除して、Apacheを再起動。phpinfo()にて5.5.30への変更を確認しました。