# 「php -v」と、「phpinfo()」 のPHPバージョンが異なるのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: php

**php -v**
・7.0.2

**phpinfo()**
・5.5.32

**異なっている場合は、「php -v」の方が正しいのでしょうか？**
[phpinfo()でのバージョン確認について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17606/phpinfo%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

Comment: リンクされている質問の内容は確認されたのでしょうか。OS等の環境、PHPのインストール方法(7.0.2 5.5.32両方)、httpサーバの設定、バージョンを確認した方法を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: リンクに挙げられた「phpinfo()でのバージョン確認について」と全く同じ症状のように見えます。コマンドラインのphpとphpinfo()を実行したphpが異なるバージョンなのでしょう。とりあえず`php -r "phpinfo();"`をコマンドラインから実行して出力されるPHP Versionを確認し、httpサーバ(Apache?)のphp周りの設定を調べてみてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

恐らく PHPが CLI 版と PHP-FPM版で異なるバージョンで複数インストールされているのでしょう。